# Firestore data retrieval of non-existing documents

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use the following code to get data from firestore that is sorted according to the date the document was updated on:

```
fun getQuery(groupID: String): Query {
        val path = FirestorePath()
        return path.getTaskCollectionRef()
            .orderBy(ActionTask.FieldNames.taskUpdatedOn.name, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .whereEqualTo(ActionTask.FieldNames.taskGroupID.name, groupID)
            .whereEqualTo(ActionTask.FieldNames.taskOpen.name, true)
    }
```

The problem is that the `.orderBy()` causes my app to display data from documents that are deleted (existed previously, now deleted).

When I remove the `.orderBy()`, I see the correct data in my app.

Comment: So you are getting data from the cache when you are doing the query?

Comment: I'm not getting data from cache. At least not deliberately. Is the API getting it from cache? I have no idea.

Comment: I ask because since Firestore is Strongly consistent, you shouldn't be getting deleted data. However, you may be getting it from the cache if [oflline mode](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline) is enabled

Comment: The offline mode is enabled by default right?

Comment: For Android and iOS, yes

Comment: Then I guess this is the problem

Comment: let me know if turning offline worked, and I will write it as an answer here to be seen by other members of the community

Comment: Yes. This solved the problem. Please put down you answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the offline mode of Firestore being active by default in your code. You should turn if off in order to avoid getting responses from the cache instead of your database.

You can find more information about the offline mode and how to disable it for Android over at [this document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline)

Hope you find this useful!